# why do I get ( Force Close ) when I want to go to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
package islam.work;
import java.net.URI;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity extends Activity {      
    MediaPlayer begin;  
    Intent inti;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        begin = MediaPlayer.create(Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity.this , R.drawable.media);
        begin.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {


                    startActivity(new Intent("islam.work.program"));//error here

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Horrendous formatting, what is the question exactly? Be as detailed as possible.

Comment: add the second activity in Manifest file......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `finally` block to

```
finally
{
    startActivity(new Intent(Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity.this,Program.class)); // where Program is second activity
}
```

And add `Program.java` in manifest file as

```
<activity
     android:label="Program"
     android:name="islam.work.Program" >
</activity>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: use `Tasbeeeee7_IslamicActivity.this` instead of `this` to pass current activity context

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have declared your activity in manifest. Most of the times people forget and spend endless time looking at the code.

Also try to do something like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```